# how can be bound that parent has only 3 child allowed from configration only

Tags: validation-rule, configuration

For example Account and Contact object Account name is Burlington we can create 3 childs only for this account and whenever we create new contact which is 4th child this will show error message that you cannot create more then 3 child record.

From Trigger it'll very easy to do but from configuration like validation rule how we can prevent.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a roll up summary to count the children and then have a validation rule to throw an error if the count of the roll up is greater than 3.

Comment: but the relationship between Account and contact is lookup. we cannot create rollup summary.

Comment: Try using Flow and Process Builder to create a rollup summary between lookups - http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2015/02/how-to-create-roll-up-summaries-using-flow.html